# Android Studio cant find the project properly

Tags: android, android-studio

This problem happened like "out of the blue". When I tried to run the application at some point it came up with

> configuration is still incorrect. do you want to edit it again

This message kept popping up, which I thought was a bit weird. So I endend up restarting Android Studio, but when it had loaded up again, all of the structure with folders etc. in the left side of the screen, were gone. Only a message saying "Nothing to show" is there now.
Also all of the files that were open before I restarted is still open, but has little "red J's" in the tap where the file name is.

The last edit to my project was that I changed the minimumSdkVersion of the gradle file, from 21 to 10.
Obviously changing this back, had no effect.

EDIT:
When I try to deploy the project anyways it gives me this error in the console:

> Error running main: Module is not found

So I have really no idea on how to fix this or what is wrong, even though I have tried to research it. 
I really hope someone can help me out or have an idea on what may be wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio at this moment.]

Comment: Try reopen same porject again with previous min sdk version.

Comment: Well, I can't really navigate to the gradle file where this property is set. Do you know another way to access it?

Comment: Open the project by clicking on the `build.gradle` and let it rebuild the entire project again.

Comment: the build.gradle file doesn't open my project

Answer (score 0):

If you build and deploy Android app from IDE/Studio to watch directly , you most likely will see Build Configuration screen and if you will clik "Run" you will get

**"Build Configuration is still incorrect, do you want to edit it again?"**

To solve it just check **"Do not launch Activity"** in Activity section of a "Run/Debug Configurations" of project.

or try these

- check for the tags they may be not closed.
- check for the package name in manifest file
- check for the edit configuration , Then, check the bottom section "Before launch: **Gradle-aware Make"**
  click on that small triangle to hide it. An error message should appear. This message may show you the error cause.

  - or Go to File->Project Structure-> Project Settings -> Modules,  Click on the green colored and add new module. select Application module and set the content root to your project module.
  - or try to update the gradle as when studio starts it looks for gradle and sometime if not found it download it, may be your gradle have crashed so update it or manually place it.

Comment: I have checked "Do not launch Activity", but it still says "Configuration is still incorrect, do you want to edit it again?" Also when I try to deploy the project it gives me this error in the console: "Error running main: Module is not found"

Comment: Module is not found is the cause when you have copy pasted the manifest or any error in the manifest ,with the package name ,or the activity you launch or the category you have written check for the speelings ,capital small name of the activity.

Comment: I haven't copy pasted the manifest nor changed it in any way when that error occurred unfortunately.

Comment: I think the option where I have to add an applicatio module, is the way to go for me.. But I really can't seem to make this right. The last attempt gave me this error: AssertionError: Already disposed: Module: 'MobilePlatformExam': Already disposed: Module: 'MobilePlatformExam'. Thanks a lot for your help btw.